# Is it possible to use tsconfig `paths` with a (project) `reference`?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am making use of [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#references) in a typescript project, and was wondering if this will work with [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths)?

Essentially this would entail creating a named path for a directory outside of the `rootDir`. Has anyone seen this done? Or do you perhaps have direct knowledge that it cannot be done?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as I posted my question, I fiddled with the path a bit more and it "just worked."

Here's the relevant code:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
     "@src/*": ["../src/*"],
   },
},
"references": [
  { "path": "../" }
],
```

Comment: paths is under compilerOptions and references is under root json 
how can this be that you placed them next to each other ?

Comment: Gosh I don't even know what app I posted this about originally, but I am sure it's just a formatting error. I'll update the code